# How to find position of multiple sub string in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a string of this type:

```
URL/X/help?
```

X stands for chars like: a,b,c etc... Only one chars in that place.
The length of URL is unknown it can be: `www.website.com` , `www.website.co.uk` , `www.website.info`  etc...

I want to find out the position of `/X/` in the string but only if `X` is: `s,b,t`

/X/  - appear once and only once in the string.

Something like:

```
select position ('/s/' or '/b/' or '/t/' in URL)
```

however this is not PostgreSQL syntax.

Is there a way to write this query except doing :

```
select position ('/s/' in URL) + 
select position ('/b/' in URL) +
select position ('/t/' in URL)
```

**EDIT:**
There are no complex cases. No need to worry about `/s/s` or `/b//s/` or `/s/g/` or `/s/..../s/` etc... Just the simple case I presented. It also guaranteed  that `/CHAR/` will appear exactly once but the char is unknown.

Comment: I think you got the best solution.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe isn't there a way to use reg expressions to handle this?

Comment: @Programmer120 what's your sample input and expected output, please edit question and fill this in. Include the most complicated combination of data you can think of to this sample so that it covers everything you want.

Comment: @Programmer120 Even if there is a way to do this with regular expressions (I can't think of one), it would certainly be slower than your idea. Regular expressions use a lot of CPU.

Comment: @KamilG. There is no complected case. This is my whole example.  /CHAR/ appear once and only once. There can't be a mix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you wanted to know if there's a way to do this using regular expression, here's one:

```
select 
  coalesce(nullif(length(regexp_replace(url, '\/[sbt]\/.*', '')), length(url))+1, 0) as pos
from ( select 'www.webexample.com/s/help?' as url union all
       select 'www.webexample.com/d/help?' as url ) t;
```

Outputs:

```
| pos |
+-----+
| 19  |
| 0   |
```

---

**How it works?**

1. Using `regexp_replace` find & replace string part starting from `/s/`, `/b/` or `/t/` to the end of string with blank character `''`
2. Calculate `length` of the result to see the position of last character before `/`
3. Apply `nullif` function which returns `NULL` if length of an url after string replacement equals length of the original url
4. Add +1 to get the position of slash right before any of characters from class: `[sbt]`
5. Apply `coalesce` function which translates `NULL` values to `0`

Thanks @Abelisto for input

Comment: Works greate except once case... when the [sbt] doesn't exist for example: `select length(regexp_replace(url, '\/[sbt]\/.*', ''))+1
from ( select 'www.webexample.com/d/help?' as url ) t`  it should give 0 in this case. Other than that works awesome

Comment: @Programmer120 `nullif(length(regexp_replace(url, '\/[sbt]\/.*', '')), length(url))+1` will return NULL if substring not found.

Comment: Adjusted my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: @KamilG. Why not just `position('|!|' in regexp_replace(url, '\/[sbt]\/.*', '|!|'))` ?

Comment: @Abelisto thanks for pointing that out. I overcomplicated things. `nullif` + `coalesce` will do the work.

Comment: @Programmer120 this answer should now satisfy your needs.